# How to make a stylesheet accessible to only one component react.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have multiple stylesheets. Let's say `navbar.css` and `footer.css`. I want to use the pseudo-element `:root` in both of these css files to define variables. However, I don't want the variables to be accessible to the other css file. When I use both of these components, the css files merge together and my styles clash. How can I prevent this?

```
App.jsx
---
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
         <Navbar/>
         <p>blah blah</p>
         <Footer/>
    }
}
```

```
Navbar.jsx
---
import React from "react";

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <div>...</div>
    }
}
```

```
Footer.jsx
---
import React from "react";

export default class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <div>...</div>
    }
}
```

```
Navbar.css
---
:root {
    bg-col: white;
}
```

```
Footer.css
---
:root {
    bg-col: black;
}
```

Now, I have shortened these files to keep it simple, but, the `bg-col` variables clash with each other. How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI you can actually add CSS variables to classes for locality, it doesn't just work for the global scope. If your two react components had a specific `className` in the main `div` you could make the CSS files say `.class_name { --bg-col: black; }`

Comment: But can I still access those variables from another selector in the same file?

Comment: [Yes](https://codepen.io/OliverBalfour/pen/eYpXvar). They won't conflict, even if you use the same variable name, demonstrated by that pen. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with CSS module. In that way, one css file is separate and independent from another. Maybe add a class to that root element and the problem is solved.

Create two files

```
Navbar.module.css
Footer.module.css
```

and in your Navbar.jsx and Footer.jsx just import these modules.

```
Navbar.jsx
---
import React from "react";
import styles from './Navbar.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <div className={styles.root}>...</div>
    }
}
```